# how to remove first 4 characters from a char array

Tags: c++, char, arrays

My current code is:

```
char* message = new char[256];

    cin.getline(message, 256);
if(message[0] == 's' && message[1] == 'a' && message[2] == 'y' && message[3] == ' ')
{
    cout << message << endl;
}
```

I am trying to have it setup so it will only print if the first 4 characters are 'say ' and it works fine however I need to figure out a way for it to remove 'say ' as well so it only shows what the person wanted to well say. Bare in mind for what I am doing it has to be a char I cannot use a string in the situation I am in. If anyone can help me figure out how to do this I will be very grateful thanks.

Comment: Use `std::string`. Really, do it. It handles the length itself, there's a `substr` function, and there's an `erase` function.

Comment: chris beat my by a few seconds. Still, I reiterate: Use std::string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply print `message + 4`

```
cout << (message + 4) << endl;
```

And then rewrite it to use std::string.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the C++ version of your C-code:

```
std::string message;
cin >> message;
if ( message.substr(0,4) == "say " )
     cout << message.substr(4);
```

Seriously, pick one. Stop believing C is C++. If you're writing C++, write C++.